# How to highlight the selected menu item

Tags: reactjs

I want to highlight the selected menu item, can anyone help?

```
 <div className="scrollmenu" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                {
                  category.map((item) => (
                    <div className="menu__wrapper">
                      <menu
                        
                        onClick={() => { showCat(item.id); showCatName(item.name); }}
                        className="mobile-cat-menu"
                      // style={{ float: "right", cursor: "pointer", paddingLeft: "0px", margin: "0px" }}
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </menu>
                    </div>
                  ))}
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `className` depending on the selected element, and use CSS to highlight it.

For example, let's assume that you want to highlight a cat called **Supercat**:

```js
<div className = "scrollmenu" style = {{ display: "flex" }}>
    {
        category.map((item) => (
        <div className = "menu__wrapper">
            <menu 
                onClick = {() => { showCat(item.id); showCatName(item.name); }}
                className = "mobile-cat-menu"
            >
            <div className = { item.name === "Supercat" ? "highlight" : "not__highlight" }>
                {item.name}
            </div>
            </menu>
        </div>
        ))
    }
</div>
```

Then use CSS:

```
.highlight{
    background: red;
}
.not__highlight{
    background: transparent;
}
```